# How to make a vector of received size?

Tags: rust

I have a vector `data` with size unknown at compile time. I want to create a new vector of the exact that size. These variants don't work:

```
let size = data.len();

let mut try1: Vec<u32> = vec![0 .. size]; //ah, you need compile-time constant
let mut try2: Vec<u32> = Vec::new(size); //ah, there is no constructors with arguments
```

I'm a bit frustrated - there is no any information in Rust API, book, reference or rustbyexample.com about how to do such simple base task with vector.
This solution works but I don't think it is good to do so, it is strange to generate elements one by one and I don't have need in any exact values of elements:

```
let mut temp: Vec<u32> = range(0u32, data.len() as u32).collect();
```

Comment: Are you trying to fill it with zeros, or have a vector preallocated to a certain length, or have a vector preallocated to a certain sized allocation (i.e. no elements)?

Comment: I want to have a vector with certain length but rubbish in elements.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `Vec::with_capacity()` constructor followed by an unsafe `set_len()` call:

```
let n = 128;
let v: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(n);
unsafe { v.set_len(n); }
v[12] = 64;  // won't panic
```

This way the vector will "extend" over the uninitialized memory. If you're going to use it as a buffer it is a valid approach, as long as the type of elements is `Copy` (primitives are ok, but it will break horribly if the type has a destructor).

Comment: I see now why it can't be done without "unsafe". With not initialized variable Rust compiler can find in code is there any usage of it before initialization. But in array case compiler can't provide this checking because array indexing can also be unknown at compile time.

Comment: I think without unsafe code the most fast variant can be just cloning original data to new array, something like let v: Vec<u32> = data.clone(); ?

Comment: Well, this particular function (`set_len()`) is `unsafe` because it may be used to cause memory corruption: if you call it with an argument greater than the capacity of the vector, you may cause buffer overflow when writing beyond the allocated capacity.

Comment: @FominArseniy, cloning the vector involves copying all of the elements. If that's what you need, go for it. BTW, preallocating a vector (even with `set_len()`) and then manually copying data to it from another vector with index assignments is going to be inefficient due to bounds checking. Using `zip()` on iterators will help, though, but `clone()` is much simpler.

Comment: Bounds checking? We can write let v : Vec<u32> = vec![]; v[100500] = x; and panic, is it bounds checking?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is. Each indexed access with `[]` involves a test that the index is inside the vector boundaries; if it isn't, a panic occurs. If you need indexing without bounds checking, there is `get_unchecked()` and `get_unchecked_mut()` functions, but they are `unsafe`, naturally.

Comment: The idea to clone vector instead of creating new one with the size of original is in that I'm forced to put some values in new vector and moreover I'm forced to put them one by one. It seems to me that cloning (with copying all elements at once) is faster than putting one by one, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right, if copying the data stored in a vector is what you need.

Comment: `set_len` can cause memory corruption even without setting it too large: the data is uninitialised and interacting with it (other than just writing to it, with `std::ptr::write`) is likely to cause undefined behaviour. (For `u32` it's mostly OK, but using `=` with any type with a destructor will cause the destructor to run on the "random" uninitialised memory.)

Comment: Yes, I should probably mention that it would only work fine with `Copy` data.

Comment: It should also be noted that `set_len` just assigns the new length, nothing more, allowing `len()` to be greater than `capacity()` thus giving access to unallocated memory.

Comment: This code is immediate UB.

Answer (score 22):

The recommended way of doing this is in fact to form an iterator and collect it to a vector. What you want is not precisely clear, however; if you want `[0, 1, 2, …, size - 1]`, you would create a range and collect it to a vector:

```
let x = (0..size).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

(`range(0, size)` is better written `(0..size)` now; the `range` function will be disappearing from the prelude soon.)

If you wish a vector of zeroes, you would instead write it thus:

```
let x = std::iter::repeat(0).take(size).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

If you merely want to preallocate the appropriate amount of space but not push values onto the vector, `Vec::with_capacity(capacity)` is what you want.

You should also consider whether you need it to be a vector or whether you can work directly with the iterator.

Comment: What I need is portion of memory with access to it. let v : Vec<u32>  = <vec with size x>; means for me that I can write to any index from 0 to size - 1 without segmentation fault: v[0] = ..., ... v[size -1] = ... operations should be valid. But I can't waste time to pre initialize that memory with values I don't even need! Analogue in C++ is int * v = new int[size];

Comment: According to "with_capacity" doc: "this function does not specify the length of the returned vector, but only the capacity", so it doesn't suit for me. It is clear that I can use it to improve perfomance by excluding reallocation issues, however I still forced to push elements in vector one by one instead of just writing directly to memory.

Comment: In order to do this, you need to have some sort of default value for the elements, which is the 'vector of zeroes' part of Chris' example.

Comment: Default values are always slower than not defined values at all. I can't imagine that language positioned as system language doesn't have method to just allocate vector in memory without any element initialization.

Comment: @FominArseniy `new T[n]` in C++ performs default initialization, which for primitives like `int` means no initialization but calls the default constructor for user-defined types. And C++ `std::vector` doesn't allow uninitialized values either (it doesn't do bounds checking, so you can write into reserved memory, but that's UB and in any case the vector won't acknowledge those elements as its size will remain 0).

Comment: @FominArseniy: I would not surprised if it was slightly slower, but have you checked?

Comment: No, I haven't checked already - still didn't understand how to work with bench module.

Answer (score 3):

Stunningly, this is (now?) doable without all the range shenanigans. The `vec!` macro supports non-constants:

```
use rand::Rng;
    
fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let size: usize = rng.gen_range(1..1000);

    let mut vec: Vec<u32> = vec![0; size]; // <--- this works

    let val = vec[0];
    println!("vec[0] = {val}.");
}
```

Without the `vec!` macro the same expression requires a constant. You do need to specify an initial value either way, but for me that's a small price to pay. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3971e565834e61d48c2413c9ccaccbc).